Micronaut programmatically add controller
I working on Java 21 JPMS module .
is there any way to dynamically register/unregister to micronaut a class annotated by @Controller ?
Actually i want to implement modular api .
Note: Each api has own jpms layer with common parent layer.

I think this is better question (if you want to test without jpms structure) :
Imagine implement watch a directory with FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService(); , then copy and paste a groovy script contain @Controller in that directory .
is there any way micronaut load that api dynamically ?
